# Dagger 2, Two dependent components cannot share the same scope

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

As a question mention, I know that Dagger 2 from the following link

https://guides.codepath.com/android/dependency-injection-with-dagger-2#scopes

> Two dependent components cannot share the same scope

However, the reason mention in the following link is not clear to me.

https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/107#issuecomment-71073298

**JackWharton said that...**

> Two components with the same scope can break scoping.
>
> From your example:
>
> Component1 c1 = Dagger_Component1.create();
>
> Component2 c2_a = Dagger_Component2.builder().component1(c1).build();
>
> Component2 c2_b = Dagger_Component2.builder().component1(c1).build();
>
> c1 has singletons which are used across c2_a and c2_b but the singletons from Component2 get separate instances in c2_a and c2_b

### How it breaks??##

c2_a will modify the scope of c1 or what it does to break?

thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say component 1 and component 2 has scope called @AwesomeScope

Let's say component 2 provides a banana for @AwesomeScope

When c1 is created, it creates awesome scope. When c2_a is created depending on c1, it doesn't create awesome scope because c1 already has awesome scope. Instead c2_a shares awesome scope created c1.

When c2_b is created, it also shares awesome scope created by c1 for the same reason as c2_a above.

From above, we can infer that c2_b and c2_a shares same awesome scope created by c1.

When c2_a tries to create a banana for the awesome scope, it traverses through dependencies to see there is another banana in awesome scope. c_2a only sees c1 has awesome scope. Since c1 doesn't have banana, c_2a creates banana and keeps it within c_2a instance because c_2a is define to have an awesome scope.

Same event occurs when c2_b is created because c2_b has no way to reach c2_a within the same awesome scope and check whether c2_a has a banana or not. Now both c1_a and c2_b have banana meaning there are 2 bananas in one awesome scope. Since only one banana should exist in each awesome scope, we can conclude that it broke the scope.